# Envers doesn't insert records

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to integrate Envers in my project. I'm using Hibernate-envers 3.5.5-Final, Hibernate-core 3.5.5-Final, spring 3.0.7.RELEASE.

For DAO Layer, I'm using a GenericDaoHibernate class.

My applicationContext.xml contains:

```
<property name="eventListeners">
                   <map>
                   <entry key="post-insert" >
                         <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                 </entry>
                    <entry key="post-update">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="post-delete">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="pre-collection-update">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="pre-collection-remove">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="post-collection-recreate">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>  
                   </map>
                </property>
```

The audit tables for the annotated classes are created, but by adding or updating a row in the entity table, no row is inserted in the _AUD tables or in the REVINFO.

So, I added a new listener org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener as :

```
<property name="eventListeners">
               <map>
               <entry key="post-insert" >
           <list>
             <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
             <bean class="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener" />
           </list>
       </entry>
                <entry key="post-update">
                 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
               </entry>
                <entry key="post-delete">
                 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
               </entry>
                <entry key="pre-collection-update">
                 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
               </entry>
                <entry key="pre-collection-remove">
                 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
               </entry>
                <entry key="post-collection-recreate">
                 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
               </entry>  
               </map>
            </property>
```

The problem persists, and now no record is inserted in the entity tables.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.

I solved the problem.

Firstibale, it seems that with the Hibernate-core 3.5.5-Final, we don't need org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener, so in our ApplicationContext-config.xml we should have just this config :

```
<property name="eventListeners">
                   <map>
                   <entry key="post-insert" >
                         <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                 </entry>
                    <entry key="post-update">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="post-delete">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="pre-collection-update">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="pre-collection-remove">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>
                    <entry key="post-collection-recreate">
                     <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
                   </entry>  
                   </map>
                </property>
```

Secondly, in our case our project uses two transction managers, so for the services annotated @Transactionnal we have to mention the name of the proper transaction manager used, that means that all services should be annotated as @Transactionnal(value="NAME_TX_MANAGER"). The source of this problem is that Envers doesn't work properly if we have an auto-commit (If I understood well its documentation).

I hope that may be helpful for the other visitors if the face the same difficulties.